# Save toggled class state using js and/or cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies

I have a banner fixed at the bottom of my website that is open by default to display important information, I also have a button that can toggle it away if the user has read the notice and wants to hide it.

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const   noticeToggle = document.querySelector('.notice__toggle'),
            notice = document.querySelector('.notice')

    noticeToggle.addEventListener('click', _ => {
        noticeToggle.classList.toggle('notice__toggle--toggled');
        notice.classList.toggle('notice--toggled');
    })
});
```

Is there a way I can use js, cookies or something else to save the state of this toggle whilst the user is on the website? Currently it only defaults to open when they navigate different pages (as expected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use localStorage to store a flag to determine the state of the banner, something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const noticeToggle = document.querySelector('.notice__toggle'),
    notice = document.querySelector('.notice')
    
  if (!!localStorage.getItem('bannerDismissed')) {
    notice.classList.add('notice--toggled'); // remove the banner
  }

  noticeToggle.addEventListener('click', _ => {
    noticeToggle.classList.toggle('notice__toggle--toggled');
    notice.classList.toggle('notice--toggled');
    localStorage.setItem('bannerDismissed', 'true');
  })
});
```

Note that I removed the reliance on jQuery in the sample code as all it was used for was the document load event handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great but I have a futher question. Is it possible to only save the state during the users current session? The banner displays information that is frequently updated and I woudn't want anyone to miss it if they have visited the site before and hidden the banner. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, in that case change `localStorage`, which is stored until manually cleared by the user in their browser settings, to `sessionStorage`, which is cleared automatically when the session ends

Answer (score 0):

Just save your switch state like `localStorage.setItem('mySwithState', 'active')`
And getting it when page loaded like `localStorage.getItem('mySwithState');`

Answer (score 0):

you can use localStorage for that.

```
// write
window.localStorage.hasReadYourInfoBox = true;

// read
const hasReadInfoBox = !!window.localStorage.hasReadYourInfoBox
```